# Compute hessian of particular function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, hessian-matrix

Consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{\|Ax\|_2^2}$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$
I want to compute the hessian of $f$. For the gradient I end up with:
$$ \nabla f(x) = \frac{-2 A^TAx}{\|Ax\|_2^4}$$. Now for the hessian I tried the following:

$$ \nabla^2 f(x) = \frac{-2 A^TA + 8 \|Ax\|_2^3 2 ( A^T A x)^T A^T A x  }{\|Ax\|_2^8}$$

I think I did a mistake here. Can maybe somebody clarify what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the gradient calculation is correct, start with:

$\begin{equation}
\nabla^2f(x) = \frac{(||Ax||^4)(-2A^TA)+(2A^TAx)(4||Ax||^3)}{||Ax||^8}
\end{equation}$

This is just the quotient rule (low dhigh - high dlow all over low squared). Now, we can make some simplifications:

$\begin{align}
\nabla^2f(x) &= \frac{-2A^TA||Ax||^4 + 8A^TAx||Ax||^3}{||Ax||^8}\\
&= \frac{-2A^TA||Ax|| + 8A^TAx}{||Ax||^5}\\
&= \frac{-2A^TA(||Ax||-4x)}{||Ax||^5}
\end{align}$

And of course this is all with respect to the $\ell^2$ norm but it should also work in general. Let me know if this makes sense or if I made any mistakes. Hope it helps!